# How to use segment() from wordsegment inside to re.sub to extract words from hashtags in python?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, data-cleaning, wordsegment

I am working on sentiment analysis of tweets using python. In the process of cleaning of tweets, I want to extract words from hashtags. I found that wordsegment library does this work very efficiently. However my issue is that, wordsegment library taking a lot of time when I applied it to complete tweet columns in my dataset using `df['tweet].apply(lambda x: segment(x))`. I think I can reduce this time by applying `segment()` operation on the hashtags. For that I first created a function as fallows:

```
def extract_words(hashtags):
    words = " ".join(segment(hashtags))
    return words
```

and then I tried to apply using  `re.sub`:

```
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'#(\w)+', extract_words, x))
```

This code did not worked and gave me an error. What can I do so that I can apply segment only on the hashtags?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) inside your `extract_words` function to get all hashtags occurrences for each tweet and place in a list. The regex should change to `(#\w+)`, placing the hashtag and the one or more quantifier inside the capturing group, this will simplify the subsequent replace function. From there you can replace each hashtag found by the result of the `segment` function for that hashtag.

Input **sample.csv**

```
tweets
"RT @NatGeo: Watch: When humans live on Mars, what exactly will they call home? https://xxxxxxx/QlJBuB6FX2 #CountdownToMars"
"RT @HodderBooks: With the delectable #ActsOfLove publishing tomorrow, here's @TalulahRiley�herself to tell you about her debut novel: https?"
"RT @solarimpulse: BREAKING: we flew 40'000km without fuel. It's a first for energy, take it further! #futureisclean https://xxxxxxx/JCvKTDBVZx"
"RT @TeslaRoadTrip: #TeslaRoadTrip All - thanks so much for following our twitter feed.  The trip was a success and everyone has diverted ..."
"RT @TeslaMotors: Agreed. @FTC affirms States to allow consumers to choose how they buy their cars. #Tesla #Michigan http://xxxxxxx/fT1JHjMpzg""
```

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import wordsegment as ws
ws.load()

def extract_words(tweet):
    hashtags = re.findall(r"(#\w+)", tweet)
    for hs in hashtags:
        words = " ".join(ws.segment(hs))
        tweet = tweet.replace(hs, words)
    return tweet

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
print(df)

df['NewTweet'] = df['tweets'].apply(lambda x: extract_words(x))
print(df)
```

Output from **NewTweet**

```
RT @NatGeo: Watch: When humans live on Mars, what exactly will they call home? https://xxxxxxx/QlJBuB6FX2 countdown to mars
RT @HodderBooks: With the delectable acts of love publishing tomorrow, here's @TalulahRiley�herself to tell you about her debut novel: https?
RT @solarimpulse: BREAKING: we flew 40'000km without fuel. It's a first for energy, take it further! future is clean https://xxxxxxx/JCvKTDBVZx
RT @TeslaRoadTrip: tesla road trip All - thanks so much for following our twitter feed.  The trip was a success and everyone has diverted ...
RT @TeslaMotors: Agreed. @FTC affirms States to allow consumers to choose how they buy their cars. tesla michigan http://xxxxxxx/fT1JHjMpzg
```